# ASP Classic insert data from array into sql databse

Tags: sql, arrays, asp-classic

I have a data coming from array like following :

*(AuthName1,AuthAddr1,AuthEmail1~AuthName2,AuthAddr2,AuthEmail2~)*

so i split it using the following code:

```
<%
dim authinfo
dim arr1

arr1 = Split(authinfo,"~")
for each item in arr1
response.write item
response.write ("<br>")
next
%>
```

It give the following result :

AuthName1,AuthAddr1,AuthEmail1
AuthName2,AuthAddr2,AuthEmail2

then i update the above code as following to split each part :

```
<%
dim authinfo
dim arr1

arr1 = Split(authinfo,"~")
for each item in arr1


arr2 = split(item,",")
for each item2 in arr2

response.Write item2
response.Write ("<br>")

response.write ("<br>")
next
%>
```

**what i want is insert each item in (arr2) into a database table using sql, that table 
is (ID, AuthorName, AuthorAddress, AuthorEmail)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO 
    [dbo].[TestTable1]
        ([F1], [F2], [F3])
VALUES
      (arr2 (0), arr2 (1), arr2 (2))
```

because "arr2" is array, you could use arr2 (0), arr2 (1), arr2 (2), where
arr2 (0) = AuthName1
arr2 (1) = AuthAddr1
arr2 (2) = AuthEmail1

also, please change from

```
    for each item2 in arr2
        response.Write item2
```

to

```
    for each item2 in arr2
        response.Write item2
    next
```

Finally:

```
dim authinfo
dim arr1

authinfo = "AuthName1,AuthAddr1,AuthEmail1~AuthName2,AuthAddr2,AuthEmail2"

arr1 = Split(authinfo,"~")

for each item in arr1
    arr2 = split(item,",")

    Response.Write arr2 (0) & ";" & arr2 (1) & ";" & arr2 (2)
    '### Your SQL statement should be there !

next
```

NOTE!
Do not forget to verify array size!

Comment: I did the following : 
`    <%
    dim authinfo
    dim arr1
    dim arr2
        authinfo = request.Form("authorsvalues")
    arr1 = Split(authinfo,"~")
    for each item in arr1
    arr2 = split(item,",")
    
    set rs1 = server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
    sql1 = " insert into Authors (AuthorName, AuthorAddress, AuthorEmail) values ('"&arr2(0)&"' , '"&arr2(1)&"' '"&arr2(2)&"') "
    next
    %>
'
but give this error : 
    `Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'    
    Subscript out of range: '[number: 0]'    
    /icepit/test.asp, line 15`
@Zam

Comment: line 15 which contain sql statement

Comment: Can you make test and write: Response.Write arr2 (1) & "<br>" & arr2 (2) 

what will be displayed?

Comment: Same error :
'22
33@33.com'
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
Subscript out of range: '[number: 1]'
/icepit/test.asp, line 13

Comment: Another note, it save the data in the table but giving that error

Comment: see changes:

  for each item2 in arr2
   response.Write item2
  next

Comment: Great, this is working .. but it repeat the sql statement 3 times

Comment: Greeeeeeaaaaaaat man .. it is working now perfectly ... i just removed that character "~" from the end of the string "authinfo" before split it, so it worked like charm. Thanks a lot guru.